# Combine arrays by element into jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, casting, jagged-arrays

I have a method which accept jagged array of Objects.

```
public void MyDataBind(object[][] data)
```

I use it like this

```
GoogleChart1.MyDataBind(new[] { new object[] { "September 1", 1 }, new object[] { "September 2", 10 } });
```

I have source data in two arrays like these and want to pass them to the method:

```
var sDate = new string[] {"September 1", "September 2"};
var iCount = new int[] { 1, 2 };
```

How can I pass, cast or transform these predefined array values to this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

even simpler and cleaner:

```
 var result = sDate.Select((s, index) => new object[] { s, iCount[index] }).ToArray();
```

A simple solution:

```
    List<object> items = new List<object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sDate.Length; i++)
        items.Add(new object[] { sDate[i], iCount[i] });
    var result = items.ToArray();
```

You can define a method Combine(T[] array1, T[] array2) so get a more generic solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using .NET 4 then the [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) method could be used to merge the two arrays:

```
MyDataBind(sDate.Zip(iCount, (s, i) => new object[] { s, i }).ToArray());
```